# How can I use the unicode characters Triangle Arrowhead in equations with LuaLatex?

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I'd like to use the unicode arrows `⭡⭧⭢⭨⭣` (U+2B60, U+2B67, U+2B62, U+2B68, U+2B63) as I think they look nicer than the built-ins. **This should work with LuaLatex**, since I need to use it for other reasons.

I'm using the atom editor with utf-8 file encoding. I have included:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand{\spinup}{⭡}
\newcommand{\spinupr}{⭧}
\newcommand{\spinright}{⭢}
\newcommand{\spindownr}{⭨}
\newcommand{\spindown}{⭣}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\spinup = \spindown
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But I don't see any symbol except the equal sign.

Comment: Make sure to use a font that actually provides the required glyph. It's not that common, many fonts don't have it. Outside of the `equation` environment you'd get a � MISSING GLYPH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use these characters you need a font which contains these characters. The default math font loaded by `unicode-math`, "Latin Modern Math", does not have them. You should get a warning in the terminal output and the log file for that along the lines of

```
Missing character: There is no ⭡ (U+2B61) in font [latinmodern-math.otf]:mode
=base;script=math;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ⭡ (U+2B61) in font [latinmodern-math.otf]:mode
=base;script=math;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ⭣ (U+2B63) in font [latinmodern-math.otf]:mode
=base;script=math;language=dflt;!
```

A font which looks similar to the default and contains these glyphs would be for example New Computer Modern Math:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{New Computer Modern Math}

\newcommand{\spinup}{⭡}
\newcommand{\spinupr}{⭧}
\newcommand{\spinright}{⭢}
\newcommand{\spindownr}{⭨}
\newcommand{\spindown}{⭣}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\spinup = \spindown
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I also had to load `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}` to make it work.

Comment: @infinitezero That's odd, the example worked without the package on my system. Anyway, if you load the package then you should not need the `\setmathfont` line.